# how can i make an installer that includes derby database?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, derby, exe4j

I'm trying to make an installer of my program. I made one thru innosetup and exe4j. I created the installer but doesn't include the derby database.I include the derby and jar files in inno setup but still doesn't work.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Are the Derby jar files written on to the target system in the folder where your application is installed? Does your installer tool provide a log file where it records what files are written to what directories?

Comment: You have to use install4j for it